# Update certain array elements of a json array in PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a table like this;

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data JSONB
);

INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES('[1,2,"a",4,"8",6]'); -- id = 1
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES('[1,2,"b",4,"7",6]'); -- id = 2
```

How to update element `data->1` and `data->3` into something else without `PL/*`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **Postgres 9.5** or later use `jsonb_set()`. See [later answer of adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804503/939860).

---

You cannot manipulate selected elements of a `json` / `jsonb` type directly. Functionality for that is still missing in **Postgres 9.4**. You have to do 3 steps:

1. Unnest / decompose the JSON value.
2. Manipulate selected elements.
3. Aggregate / compose the value back again.

To replace the **3rd element of the json array** (`data->3`) in the row with `id = 1` with a given (new) value (`'<new_value>'`):

```sql
UPDATE test t
SET    data = t2.data
FROM  (
   SELECT id, array_to_json(
                 array_agg(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN '<new_value>' ELSE elem END))
              ) AS data
   FROM   test t2
        , json_array_elements_text(t2.data) WITH ORDINALITY x(elem, rn)         
   WHERE  id = 1
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t2
WHERE  t.id = t2.id
AND    t.data <> t2.data; -- avoid empty updates
```

About `json_array_elements_text()`:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

About `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Comment: Functions to transform jsonb values should be coming in 9.5. There's nothing inherently different to any kind of other function that takes inputs and produces outputs. It's mostly that nobody's implemented functions to replace elements, etc, yet.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this from PostgreSQL 9.5 with [jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```sql
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES('[1,2,"a",4,"8",6]');
UPDATE test SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{2}','"b"', false) WHERE id = 1
```

Try it out with a simple select:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_set('[1,2,"a",4,"8",6]', '{2}','"b"', false)
-- [1, 2, "b", 4, "8", 6]
```

And if you want to update two fields you can do:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_set(jsonb_set('[1,2,"a",4,"8",6]', '{0}','100', false), '{2}','"b"', false)
-- [100, 2, "b", 4, "8", 6]
```